# array based on max and less than?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013

I'm not sure if I'm over complicating this...
basically I'd like to have a formula which is
if the c column is less than 6, then look up the max value in B but display the value of C

so far I have this but I'd like it to show 2, not 437

{=MAX(IF(C2:C12<6,B2:B12, 0))}

any advice is appreciated.  i'm shy, be nice..thanks

```
A       B       C 
cat     110     3
dog     148     4
rooster  36     7
duck     32     8
pig     437     2
horse    44     6
eagle   215     5
dolphin  21     1
panda     2     9
iguana  257    10
fish    199    11
```

edit:

maybe something like 
{=INDEX(C2:C12,MATCH(MAX(IF(C2:C12<6,C2:C12)),C2:C12,0))}

but I don't see where to put b2:b12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really need two conditions

1) Column B is equal to `=MAX(IF(C2:C12<6,B2:B12))`

2) Column C is `<6`

so you can `INDEX` column C when those two are met, i.e.

`=INDEX(C2:C12,MATCH(1,(B2:B12=MAX(IF(C2:C12<6,B2:B12)))*(C2:C12<6),0))`

confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

Comment: WORKS omg thank you, this was a lot more complicated than i thought!!!!

Comment: i tried to give you a point too but i don't have enough posts, can't thank you enough

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there..
Basically if `C<6` , find max of B , lookup it in B:C and display corresponding C

```
{=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(MAX(IF(C2:C12<6,B2:B12, 0)),B2:C12,2,FALSE),0)}
```

Since your question doesn't clarify what if `c>=6` I assume you don't want value.
Can answer more precisely if you clarify.

Mark this as answer if that's correct.
Hope this helps!

Comment: make sure column b dont have 0 value.. as if clause returns 0 and vlookup will still bring that value. In that case replace 0 with some other value in this formula.e.g.
{=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(MAX(IF(C2:C12<6,B2:B12, -1)),B2:C12,2,FALSE),-1)}

Comment: is it possible to use index instead of vlookup...like  =INDEX(C2:C12,MATCH(MAX(IF(C2:C12<6,C2:C12)),C2:C12,0))  is close but i don't see where I put b2:b12?  Thank you!

Comment: @hollyolly Please see my answer if you would like a single INDEX() solution

Answer (score 0):

```
{=IF(C2<6,INDEX($C$2:$C$12,MATCH(MAX($B$2:$B$12),$B$2:$B$12,0)),0)}
```

Comment: this is close but it gives me 10 instead of 2? i think it's looking at the entire b column

Comment: I think it depends on how you put your formula, should work fine if you put it in D2 then copy paste down, if you want to validate D2:D12 at once use {=IF(C2:C12<6,INDEX($C$2:$C$12,MATCH(MAX($B$2:$B$12),$B$2:$B$12,0)),0)}

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explain how it works.

Answer (score 0):

As I could see you requested a single INDEX formula:

`{=INDEX($C$2:$C$12,MATCH(MAX(IF($C$2:$C$12<6,$B$2:$B$12,0),0),IF($C$2:$C$12<6,$B$2:$B$12,0),0))}`

This is an array formula, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> while still in the formula bar.

Lets break this down.

`=INDEX(C:C,` - Index column C as these are the values you want returned

`MATCH(IF(C:C<6,B:B,0),` - Find the largest value from the following array in the array and return it's relative position for INDEX()

`IF(C:C<6,B:B,0),0))` - If the value in column c is less than 6 then add the column B value to the array, otherwise add 0

Comment: Thanks!  I missed this

Comment: Works great.  Thanks for the detailed explanation..when I get enough credits I'll give you a point.  I'm not sure if I can select 2 answers as correct.